# How to integrate Workligt Studio 6 with WAS ND 8.5.5 in RAD 9

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, rad, websphere-8, worklight-studio

I am having troubles with integration WAS [ND/BASE] 8.5 or WAS [ND/BASE] 8.5.5 with Worklight Studio 6.0 in Eclipse or in RAD 9.

**What I did:**

1. Installed RAD 9
2. Installed WAS TE 8.5.5, created AppSrv profile,
   secured
3. Installed Worklight 6.0 on the WAS - worklight console
   application installed fine
4. Installed Worklight Studio 6.0 in RAD 9
5. Created new Hybrid project in fresh workspace

Now, I am trying to have the project run on WAS 8.5.5 (full profile) server, and Worklight Studio 6 does not support it? When I open "Change Worklight Target Server", create new WAS BASE 8.5.5 server - the server not appear in the drop down for that dialog.

**NOTE:** Same I had with Eclipse 4.2.2 and standalone WAS 8.5.0.2, using Worklight 6 and Worklight Studio 6. No any support for Websphere full profile. Did I do it wrong?

What I want to do: integrate Eclipse with Worklight Studio with WAS ND (not Liberty Profile) as server for testing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid the Worklight Studio server integration only works with Liberty profile and Tomcat but not with WAS ND.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, because I was not able to read it in the documentation. What I saw in the documentation (compatibility matrix) that Workligh 6 is compatible with all flavors of WAS, starting 7 and ending 8.5.5.

What options are for developer who wants to develop for WAS 8.5.5 full profile? Create WARs and deploy with scripts? Is the debugging possible in that approach? I would consider test on Liberty Profile, but seems we need to use DynaCache (part of WAS full profile) and it's available via JNDI in WAS full profile and configurable via web admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the Worklight Studio server integration only works with Liberty profile and Tomcat but not with WAS ND. 
Don't understand me wrong, even if your scenario fails to work, Worklight WAR will still work as expected on WAS ND as indicated in the Worklight Info-Center.

For debugging that , I suggest you deploy the Studio generated WAR to the WAS server (manually). Then modify the server instance settings and enable its debug mode (see JVM settings in WAS Info Center) and from your eclipse: start remote debug (defult port 7777) the Java code.