# Worklight Studio + WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5 => deploy on WAS ND 8.5.5

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, websphere-liberty

As far as I know Worklight Studio does not support integration within IDE with WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment, and we are constrained to use WAS ND 8.5.5 for hosting of application due to corporate hosting environment restrictions.

The plan is to use: Worklight Studio + WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5 on development machines, and then move the WAR file to corporate hosting environment with WAS ND 8.5.5.

Are there concerns if this may not work? Maybe there are other suggestions on how organize development and debugging of Workligh application (including Java Adapters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the [IBM Worklight System Requirements website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838) that [WAS ND 8.5.5 is supported](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=66C745D01E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36) when it comes to Production environment. It is indeed not supported in Worklight Studio.

As for concerns, as there are current customers in production (live) in very large scales who use WAS ND with Worklight, things seem to be OK.

Related question:

- [How to integrate Workligt Studio 6 with WAS ND 8.5.5 in RAD 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027413/how-to-integrate-workligt-studio-6-with-was-nd-8-5-5-in-rad-9)

Comment: Could you tell what the customer you referred uses for development? Same what I mentioned in the question: combination of  Worklight Studio + WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5, or something different?

Comment: You do not have other options other than Tomcat or Liberty Profile when using Worklight Studio, so...